# Can anyone explain this array declaration to me?

Tags: ruby, arrays, declaration

just wondering the difference between the presence of the last comma in the array, if there is any at all

```
>> [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]

>> [1,2,3,]
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

The second array still works, no exception raised

Thanks

Comment: I suggest that you edit the question title into something a bit more explanatory.

Comment: I cleaned it up for him a little

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no difference. In Ruby, you're free to add a trailing comma to an array. It makes syntax like this:

```
a = [
  1,
  2,
  3,
]
```

A bit nicer, in some cases (e.g., if you want to add an element, you simply add a `4,` line and don't have to worry about checking for a comma on the last line).

Comment: it doesn't add null or anything?  Array length is the same w/ or w/o the comma?

Comment: No, no null value is added -- the array just contains the elements 1,2,3 in either case.

Comment: I guess there is no difference really eh? It really is just out of curiosity, I was coding and found something like this so I guess I would ask all you smart folks here.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a error, just a empty value(ignored by the compiler), but I suggest you to read [Understanding Ruby Arrays](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Understanding_Ruby_Arrays)

Comment: Where exactly does that link mention optional trailing comma?

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing special about arrays.

```
[1,2,3]
```

is the same as

```
Array.[](1,2,3)
```

so the values are just method call parameters. The same applies to

```
{a: 1, b: 2}
```

which is the same as

```
Hash.[](:a, 1, :b, 2)
```

And the reason trailing commas are allowed in method-call parameters is just because Ruby is designed like that, for the reasons of convenience that `@mipadi` mentioned.